# Find the value of $\frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{42} + \frac{1}{56} + \frac{1}{72} + \frac{1}{90}$

Tags: summation, contest-math

Find the value of $p+q$, where $p$ and $q$ are two positive integers such that $p$ and $q$ have no common factor larger than $1$ and

$$\frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{42} + \frac{1}{56} + \frac{1}{72} + \frac{1}{90} = \frac{p}{q}.$$

By using Wolfram Alpha, I obtain the sum is $\frac{3}{20}$. But I have no idea on how to obtain the sum.

Any hint would be appreaciated.

[The question is taken from SMO 2015 Junior section]

Comment: Well the standard way is to put them over a common denominater, add, and if nesc reduce.  Did you have trouble doing that?

Comment: "I obtain the sum is 3/20. But I have no idea on how to obtain the sum."  You don't know how to add 3 and 20?

Comment: @fleablood: I mean I don't know how to obtain the sum $3/20$, not the final answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can observe that
\begin{align}
20&=4\cdot 5\\
30&=5\cdot6\\
42&=6\cdot7\\
56&=7\cdot8\\
72&=8\cdot9\\
90&=9\cdot10.
\end{align}
Can you use partial fraction?

Comment: Good observation, but I think it easier to see that the difference of two consecutive elements is increased by 2: $10, 12, 14, 16, 18...$, what indeed correspond to $(a)_2-(a-1)_2=2(a-1)$

Answer (score 3):

We  know that 
$$
S_n=\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2}+ \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3}+ \cdots+ \frac{1}{(n-1)n}=1-\frac{1}{n}
$$
Then yours sum is exactly $$S_{10}-S_4=(1-\frac{1}{10})-(1-\frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{10}=\frac{5-2}{20}=\frac{3}{20}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$1/20 + 1/30 + 1/42 + 1/56 + 1/72 + 1/90 = $

$1/4*5 + 1/5*6 + 1/6*7 + 1/7*8 + 1/8*9 + 1/9*10 = $

Note:  $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{(n +1)(n +2)} = \frac{n+2 + n}{n(n+1)(n+2} = \frac {2n + 1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{2}{n(n+2)}$

And $\frac{k}{n(n+k)} + \frac{1}{(n+k)(n + k + 1)} = \frac{k(n + k + 1) + n}{n(n+k)(n + k + 1)} = \frac{(k + 1)n + (k+1)k}{n(n+k)(n+k + 1)} = \frac{k+1}{n(n+ k + 1)}$.

So...

$1/4*5 + 1/5*6 + 1/6*7 + 1/7*8 + 1/8*9 + 1/9*10 = $

$2/4*6 + 1/6*7 + 1/7*8 + 1/8*9 + 1/9*10 = $

$3/4*7 + 1/7*8 + 1/8*9 + 1/9*10 = $

$4/4*8 + 1/8*9 + 1/9*10 = $

$5/4*9 + 1/9*10 = $

$6/4*10 =  3/20 = p/q$

$p + q = 3 + 20 = 23$.